# Computed value runs every time value is updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a loop that outputs checkboxes:

```
<div v-for="(value, key) in optionsObject" :key="key">
```

In computed I check whether the prop `options` is an object or an array (if array I make they key from the array values)...

```
computed: {
        optionsObject() {
            return _.isPlainObject(this.options) ? this.options : _.zipObject(this.options, this.options);
        }
    }
```

But everytime the checkbox is changed, it runs the computed `optionsObject` again. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: why not generating the optionsObject in mounted hook and assigning it to component data?

Comment: That's exactly what a computed property does.

Comment: Is there a reason for making a computed propertie for this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how a computed property in Vue works. It refresh when a property that it depends on changes. For performances this is a huge advantage compared to a method(), as noted in the [**docs**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

> Instead of a computed property, we can define the same function as a
> method. For the end result, the two approaches are indeed exactly the
> same. **However, the difference is that computed properties are cached
> based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only
> re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.**